# Best type of wood for making a small table

Tags: table-making

I am trying to build a small wooden table to rest my guitar amplifier ontop of and hide my pedal board underneath. I need the table top to be around 30'' x 10'' and about 12'' high. What type of wood should I buy for this project? My amp weighs around 50lbs and will be the only substantial item ontop of it. Also, what is the best way for securing the legs onto the table? I have very basic tools (mostly a power drill) but have a friend who has a table saw that I might be able to use.

I'd also like to paint the table later on, so something that takes paint well would be appreciated. I don't need anything particularly fancy, just whatever is cheapest and gets the job done, but I haven't tried a project like this before and am mostly clueless on where to start.

Thanks

Comment: This question is broad enough that almost any species could be made to work.  I also think that you should probably split this up into two questions, one asking about what material to use and another asking about the construction techniques.

Comment: If paint is the destination, there's absolutely nothing wrong with plywood. Doesn't even have to be nice Baltic Birch ply, just a decent sheet of sanded A-A.

Answer (score 1):

(This question isn't really an ideal fit for this site, as you're basically asking "how do I do this project".  The question of species is really opinion-based because almost anything would work.  Since you're new here, though, I'll give you an answer anyways.)

If you're painting it then poplar is a good choice. It's easy to work with and strong enough. It takes paint well and it's fairly cheap. The biggest downside is that if you don't paint it it's not very pretty, as it can have greenish coloration.

What I'd do is get a poplar 1x10 board from a big box store.  Try to find one that is as straight and flat as possible.  Start by crosscutting off a 30" long piece for the top.  (The table saw is NOT a good way to do this, so you'll also need a circular saw, miter saw, hand saw, or possibly a jig saw.)

Then rip 8 pieces 1 1/2" wide and a foot long and laminate them together for the legs.  You'll need some clamps for this, but it's small enough that you could just use cheap C-clamps.

Cut some aprons a few inches wide.  To join them to the legs I'd use dowel joints.  You can get a kit that includes the dowels, centering pins, a drill bit and stop collar for a few bucks at the home center when you're picking up your lumber.  Basically you drill holes in the aprons, put the pins in those holes, line them up with the legs and press the pins into the legs to mark where to drill into them.  Use wood glue, like titebond 3, on the dowels and holes.

Normally tabletops need to be attached in a way that will allow for wood movement.  For something this small that can be as simple as only attaching the top by screwing through the centers of the short aprons.  (Attaching it the top to the long aprons would prevent the top from moving and lead to some kind of failure in the long run.)

Comment: Kudos, that's about as all-inclusive and Answer as one could hope for for such an open-ended Q. Re. wood movement, I presume you're also assuming 10" deep and 30" wide? At 10" seasonal movement should be so small it can nearly be ignored, but especially if the item will be painted (paint being significantly better at excluding humidity than most clear finishes, and not only because it tends to be applied more thickly).

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  10" is pretty small...you could probably get away with just screwing through all four aprons

Comment: Yeah, lots of boxes and smaller tables out there with solid-wood tops where there's minimal or no allowance made for movement. But obviously wood selection does begin to matter and a very flat-sawn piece with steeply curving grain (possibly typical of a big-box hardwood 1x10?) can move a lot more than a QS or RS piece.